# Error do_shortcode In WooCommerce Template

Tags: shortcode, templates, woocommerce-offtopic

I’m tryin to insert shortcode through add_action :

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'quotation_form', 61);
function quotation_form()
{
$produk = get_the_title();
$shortkode = sprintf(
'[zendesk_request_form size="3" group="extra-field" subject="Quotation For %s"]',
$produk
);
$shortkode = do_shortcode( $shortkode );
echo $shortkode;
}
```

But gettin error after the shortcode displayed:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_upsells() on null in /home/dev/wp-content/themes/dummy-child/woocommerce/single-product/up-sells.php:25

The line related with error above:

```
if ( ! $upsells = $product->get_upsells() ) {
return;
}
```

`Source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/up-sells.php`

So I think:

1. The shortcode itself displaying properly but script stop executed with error above
2. When I tried to output *quotation_form* function with return /
   echo-ing plain text or html, its working perfectly without any error

My question is:
How the right way to insert shortcode in WooCommerce template?
Is it possible to doing that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with dirty way.. hope someone else can provide more efficient solution, my final working code for problem above:

```
$shortkode = '[zendesk_request_form size="3" group="extra-field" subject="Quotation For -wkwkwk-"]';
$shortkode = do_shortcode( $shortkode );
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'quotation_form', 61);
function quotation_form()
{
$produk = get_the_title();
global $shortkode;
$shortkode = str_replace("-wkwkwk-", $produk, $shortkode);
echo $shortkode;
}
```

So i move out do_shorcode outside function, then declare it as global variable.
The problem is about my $produk variable will not working if declare it outside Wordpress page, so I'm using str_replace to replacing pre product title

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the $product variable is not defined. I see two possible solutions:

- If you only render the shortcode on a product page, then write `global $product;` at the beginning of your function.
- Else you need to define which product to take: `global $product; $product_obj = new WC_Product_Factory(); $product = $product_obj->get_product( "insert product id" );`. Also write this at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Actually I render it in functions page, still no luck, and also have tried directly to product page (in meta.php) still not working.

Comment: So do you think this is about scope issue? thank you for the clue, I will find out now

Comment: I almost there... I moving out do_shortcode outside function and its work except I can grab the $product var:

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'quotation_form', 61);
function quotation_form()
{
global $shortkode
echo $shortkode;
}

Comment: Try to debug the $product variable in your quotation_form. Add `code`global $product; var_dump($product);`code`. What does this variable display?